# How to display a dialog from a broadcast reciever

Tags: android

I have a broadcast reciever set up in my android manifest file. However I need to show a dialog when some condition happens. I realise that the application context will not work for dialogs and I need to show it on an activity context. But even if I do that , then the background screen becomes black and blocks the current activity. I dont want that to happen . I want the popup tp overlay over the existing screen. What I have tried:

In the activity I call from my `BroadcastReciever`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Manifest of the activity:

```
android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent"
android:windowIsTranslucent="true"
android:windowAnimationStyle="@android:style/Animation.Translucent"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
startActivity()
```

and apply `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to start an Activity to be able to do this.  BroadcastReceivers will exit immediately when onReceive finishes.  If you use a dialog themed Activity it will have the same appearance as a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need something called Global or Super dialog for this

Please check http://www.sherif.mobi/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html and this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcKmuj9RNDU)

You can get source code for this on [Github](https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/Super-Dialogs/) also

Hope this will solve concern you have with dialog